# Databricks - incrementally load Delta Live Table with Streaming Table that uses APPLY CHANGES INTO as source

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

**Summary:**
I created a Delta Live Table pipeline using a streaming table (with APPLY CHANGES INTO) based on an append-only source.

I expected the downstream Delta Live Table to be incrementally updated on subsequent executions of the pipeline, but the event log shows that it is always fully recomputed.

Details from the event log:

- This event is associated with bronze_table_clean (Materialized view).
- planning_information: Flow bronze_table_clean has been planned in DLT to be executed as COMPLETE_RECOMPUTE.

**Detail:**
Is it possible to incrementally load a Delta Live Table that uses a Streaming Table as its source, where the Streaming Table uses APPLY CHANGES INTO?  Or does APPLY CHANGES INTO break the ability to incrementally load a Delta Live Table?  I have found no documentation to support either claim.

For example, I have a streaming table that uses APPLY CHANGES INTO defined as shown below.  The table it uses as a source `stream(bronze_catalog.bronze_schema.bronze_table)` is only ever appended to.

```
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING TABLE bronze_table_stream;
APPLY CHANGES INTO
  live.bronze_table_stream
FROM
  stream(bronze_catalog.bronze_schema.bronze_table)
KEYS
  (`Id`)
APPLY AS DELETE WHEN
  `__$operation` = 1
SEQUENCE BY
  `__$seqval`
COLUMNS * EXCEPT
  (`__$start_lsn`, `__$operation`, `__$update_mask`, `__$seqval`)
STORED AS
  SCD TYPE 1;
```

The subsequent Delta Live table is always fully recomputed instead of incrementally updated.

```
CREATE OR REFRESH LIVE TABLE bronze_table_clean
(
  CONSTRAINT valid_id             EXPECT (`Id` IS NOT NULL AND TYPEOF(`Id`) = 'int')  ON VIOLATION FAIL UPDATE
)
AS SELECT
   `Id`,
  `OtherColumn1`,
  `OtherColumn2`
FROM bronze_catalog.bronze_schema.bronze_table_stream
```